# Physics Calculus Problem

Tags: physics

Given that velocity is given by $v(t) =\sin(t^2)$, at what time does the total distance equal $1$?

I have no clue how to solve this, since I cannot integrate the function

Answer (score 2):

You can do it numerically.  The distance traveled is the integral of the absolute value of the velocity.  The velocity turns around at $t=\sqrt \pi$, so we can do $$\int_0^{\sqrt \pi} \sin x^2 \; dx \approx 0.894381$$ then we need to solve $\int_{\sqrt \pi}^t \sin x^2 \; dx=-0.105619$ I fed NSolve[Integrate[-Sin[x^2], {x, Sqrt[Pi], t}]==0.105619] to [Alpha in the cloud](https://sandbox.open.wolframcloud.com/app/objects/868e11d4-3226-456a-8533-9e412b3bcb26#sidebar=compute) (but I am told the link doesn't work for others) and got $t \approx 1.51436$ but we want a value of $t$ that is greater than $\sqrt \pi \approx 1.772454$   satish ramanathan reports the value as $t \approx 2.0194$

Comment: Surely you mean $\sin x^2$ and not $\sin^2 x$

Comment: Does it not turn around again between $\sqrt{\pi}$ and $t \approx 1.51436$? Also, your link to WolframAlpha doesn't work.

Comment: @ZainPatel:  Thanks.  Fixed.

Comment: @TheoreticalEconomist: No, the next turning is $\sqrt{2 \pi} \approx 2.5066$.  The link is to Alpha in the cloud, which I have clicked on and it works for me.  Maybe I have browser history that makes it work.

Comment: @RossMillikan Yes, I did see that the next turning point is after the time you find. Your link just says I do not have permission to access this item.

Comment: @TheoreticalEconomist:  What I put in was NSolve[Integrate[-Sin[x^2], {x, Sqrt[Pi], t}]==0.105619]  Maybe you can put that into Alpha or Alpha in the cloud and get it to work.

Comment: @Ross:  I think t = 2.0194.  From t = 0 to 1.772454 ( sqrt(pi)) it goes a distance equal to .894831.  Then from t = 1.772454 to t = 2.0194, it goes in the negative direction of a distance = -0.1056019.  So the distance is = 1.  I think if put add these you get the distance to be 1.  Will you agree

Comment: @satishramanathan:  that makes sense.  The root I have is spurious.  Over (1.51, \sqrt \pi)$ we have $sin(x^2) \gt 0$ so the fact that the upper limit of the integral is lower than the bottom makes the integral negative.  I can't figure out how to get Alpha to give me that root.  May I incorporate it into the answer?

Comment: No problem, Ross yes you can incorporate it to your answer

Comment: @Ross Millikan, I think the question was copied wrongly.  It should have been $v(t) = t.sin(t^2)$ to make the question solvable. The OP must have (my guess) copied the problem wrongly!!

Answer (score 0):

By definition, the displacement is $r(b) - r(a)$ where $r(t)$ is the position of the object at time $t$, and $r(a), r(b)$ are the position of the object at the start and end time respectively, and $r(t) = \displaystyle \int_{a}^t v(u)du$, whereas $a$ is the starting time and $t$ is the end time. Thus for your question, you solve: $ \displaystyle \int_{0}^t \sin(u^2)du = 1$, and you can use approximation formula to integrate the left side of the equation.